# What's the most appropriate HTTP status for a resource collection not found?

Tags: rest, http, http-status-code-404

Our application in question doesn't deal with a resource directly, or support the various HTTP verbs with respect to creating, updating, deleting a resource. We mostly have "finder" methods that return a collection of resources. So we may have a URL like `/users?firstName=john` but not `/users/1`.

The question we're debating is what's the most appropriate HTTP status code if no users are found that have first names "john". My opinion is that 204 should be returned indicating an empty collection, but not 404, because the collection itself is not a resource, and hence "resource not found" is not a valid response. [RFC 3986, section 3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) says -

> The query component contains non-hierarchical data that, along with
> data in the path component (Section 3.3), serves to identify a
> resource...

Nothing is said about a collection of resources.

Thoughts?

Comment: I'm disappointed to see someone voted to close the topic, whereas, there's clearly no consensus on this topic. If that person had an answer, they should have posted it instead of trying to close a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 6):

I agree that a 404 status wouldn't be appropriate here. I would personally use a 200 status and an empty collection, since that clearly represents a "no results" response.

Comment: Why not 204 as in my post, which says no content? Nothing about 200 indicates no content.

Comment: This is admittedly pretty opinion-y (REST is funny like that), but as a client I'd expect some sort of result to come back from a query even if that result was an empty collection. A 204 with no response body would surprise me.

That being said, neither is right or wrong: if a 204 and no body makes more sense to you, go for it!

Comment: @lutz-horn, brad-melanson, I went back and read Roy Fielding’s original [PhD dissertation](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm). In section 5.2.1.1 Resources and Resource Identifiers
> "The key abstraction of information in REST is a resource. Any information that can be named can be a resource: a document or image, a temporal service (e.g. "today's weather in Los Angeles"), a collection of other resources, a non-virtual object (e.g. a person), and so on."

Based on that, 404 for any resource not found, including collections, seems the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

What you are using are collections resources with filters (the query parameters). Every request to a collection resource should return a collection (maybe a JSON array).

- If no filter is applied, the complete (perhaps paged) collection is resource.
- If a filter is appllied and there are matches, a collection containing the matches is returned.
- If a filter is applied and there are *no* matches, an *empty* collection is returned.

Note that in all cases, a collectin is returned, not matter of there are one, none, or exactly one match. Because of this, the response is never empty but contains at least an empty array, if you use JSON.

The HTTP response header to use must be `200 OK`. It is up to the client to parse the resource representation and detect that it is perhaps empty.

Comment: According to RFC 3986 as in my post, query parameters are as good as path variables for identification of a resource. I didn't find any support for your statement that they are "filters" in the RFC.
Also, for status, why do you think the status "must" be 200? Can you refer to any standard literature in support of that statement?

Comment: You are correct that query parameters are part of the URI that is used to identify a resource. The question is: What is the resource? If you have a *collection resource* common practice is to use HTTP response and status codes as described in my answer. If you don't agree that the resource is the collection, please tell us what your resource is.

Comment: In my URL example, `/users?firstName=john`, `User` is a resource. Unless the collection has it's own id, it can't be considered as a resource. It's certainly not common to consider a collection as a resource because `/users/1` doesn't give you a user collection with id 1, it gives you a user with id 1.

Comment: What does `/users` give you? What is the result of `/users?firstName=john` if there are more than one user with the first name `john`?

Comment: `GET /users` will return all users as per convention.

Comment: So `/users` is a collection resource. It is common usage (not defined in any standard) to use query parameters as filters on such collection resources. But if you model your resources differently, you can of course do so. Both HTTP and REST say nothing about it.

Comment: See my comment to brad-melanson's answer above.